# Member of an owl:Class versus owl:NamedIndividual

Tags: owl, reasoning, turtle-rdf

Is it right, that in OWL-DL, if some :x has an rdf:type of *something which is an owl:Class*, e.g. :Car

```
:Car  rdf:type  owl:Class .
:x    rdf:type     :Car .
```

or equivalent

```
:Car  a  owl:Class .
:x    a     :Car .
```

it *cannot* be deduced, that :x must be an owl:(Named)Individual, thus one have to specify that additional fact always manually?

```
:x  a          :Car                ;
    a          owl:NamedIndividual ;
    :hasType   :Ford               ;
    :hasColor  "red"               .
```

Comment: Interesting question!  Do note that there are possibly two things at play here:  OWL-DL semantics, and the mapping between OWL ontologies and RDF.  OWL semantics shouldn't, I think, ever let you infer RDF triples, but rather new OWL assertions, and those are what would be mapped to RDF triples.

Comment: For instance, if you search in https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-direct-semantics-20121211/ for "NamedIndividual" there are no hits.

Comment: @Joshua: by now i merely use owl:NamedIndividual to mark individuals in order to get them back by Sparql queries. But does the existence of this information also affect a reasoner (like Stardog, Pellet, Hermite) in any way? (I think your answer will be 'no' ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OWL and RDF are different things.  OWL ontologies can be represented in RDF, by following the rules specified in the [OWL 2 Web Ontology Language
Mapping to RDF Graphs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-mapping-to-rdf-20121211/) document.  If you have a look in there, the ways that owl:NamedIndividual are used are:

If an ontology contains the axiom:

> Declaration( NamedIndividual( *:a ) )

then the RDF mapping contains the triple:

```
T(*:a) rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual .
```

and similarly, if an RDF mapping contains:

```
*:x rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual .
```

then the ontology contains

> Declaration( NamedIndividual( *:x ) )

(and there's one more case for annotated axioms, but it's essentially the same).

In looking though some more of the semantics documents, I don't see any other places (except for enumerated class expressions) that permit adding an `x rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual` RDF triple or inferring `NamedIndividual(x)`.